# Problems with Google Colab Pro charging

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google charged me more than once for the cost of Google Colab Pro, and I need to get that money back because the first card I used was from Colombia and it didn't give me that address, but I never gave the option to buy. I had to use an American card, who do I have to talk to to reverse that money that they charged me too much?

Answer (score 0):

This [notebook](https://github.com/Harshil-Shah99/Comparison-of-Deep-Convolutional-Neural-Networks-on-Kuzushiji-Datasets/blob/master/VGG16_K49.ipynb) used Google Colab Pro and written down near the footer it says:

> If you encounter errors or other issues with billing (payments) for
> Colab Pro, please email colab-billing@google.com.